# How to install Wi-Fi usb adapter drivers on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, usb, drivers

I bought an [EDUP USB Nano Adapter EP-N8531](http://www.edupdriver.com/edup-ep-n8531-mini-150mbps-802-11ngb-usb-wireless-nano-adapter/) and I have to install the driver that I found in the included CD. I’m using a MacBook Pro with Mac OS X 10.8.5.

I have the following files (in the `mac` directory):

[image]

In the nano adapter case there's an instruction page where the supported systems are: XP / VISTA / WIN 7 / MAC / LINUX.

The system does not recognize any of these extensions; how can I do?

Comment: The device you purchase does not supply OS X drivers

Comment: @Ramhound I edited my question, please read it again.

Comment: Without a copy of the instructions I can only assume the instructions are not valid because the content if the cd does not contain the required files. Furthermore the product website itself does not indicate nor is there any evidence their product supports OS X.  The hardware per the specifications does not support OS x

Comment: Your directory output looks a lot like a partition table.

Answer (score 2):

There's a better way to do this - a little bit of googling suggests this uses a Ralink RT5370 chipset (Apparently my favourite crapgadget vendor sells this specific model, and had it listed with its chipset). Ralink merged with mediatek, and this is the [driver download page](http://www.mediatek.com/_en/07_downloads/01_windows.php?sn=502) as of when I posted the answer. In most cases, the standard ralink driver will work perfectly well.